# PCA9685 PWM with servo 8.4 V

Tags: raspberry-pi, servo

I want to drive in Raspberry Pi this [servo](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005001349111076.html) with max power to get max torque available, 8.4 V with 4.5 A, but I haven't found any PWM servo driver I2C interface which can stand the 8.4 V.

The [pca9685](https://www.arduino-tech.com/pca9685-16-channel-12-bit-pwm-servo-motor-driver-i2c-module-for-arduino-robot/)  spec shows max 6 VDC for the servo.

The servo spec says the voltage range up to 8.4 V max, with 8.4 V I get more torque which is what I need.

The servo spec: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hc5fcdd67e7824d469fe6150a7f2e3320d.jpg

What can I do to run that servo at full power? Is there any other PWM servo driver I2C interface board that I can use?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a discussion forum, nor a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line personal consultancy. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract.

Comment: Counter question; does the servo PWM input actually need 8.4V? Check the servo specs about supported voltage range.

Comment: It is from 6v to 8.4v max, with 8.4v I get more torque which is what I need. https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hc5fcdd67e7824d469fe6150a7f2e3320d.jpg

Comment: As said before, please edit your question to add new information, don't put it in comments. Otherwise, people have to piece the question together to understand it all. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any problem.  (1) Your servo's input signal is the pretty standard 3V3~5V0 pulse, and of course pca9685 can handle it. (2) Your servo's power input is max 8.4V so you just give it 8.4V. (3) If you are using more that a couple of servos, I don't recommend to power the servos through pca9685, because there is not enough space for a big decoupling cap (I usually use 1,0000uF).  (3) The standard TowerPro  servo can handle 7.5V max, so I usually supply 6V ~ 7.5V through the pca9685.

Comment: (4) pca9685 servo pwr on brd cap (10V, 1,000uF). I usually replace it by 16V+ 10,000uF, and use 7V5. (5) References: (a) RPi4B PCA9685 PWM Controlling Many Servos:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102269/rpi4b-pca9685-pwm-controlling-many-servos,

(b) IIC 16 Channel PWM, PCA9685 Board - AliExpress US$6.30
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005002647250500.html?spm=a2g0o.search0302.0.0.58eb4dea1r0BhG&algo_pvid=9c2d9d4c-8d90-44bd-a4e6-4c82bd03df83&aem_p4p_detail=202201051839397487201816647840044791703&algo_exp_id=9c2d9d4c-8d90-44bd-a4e6-4c82bd03df83-3.

Comment: (6) BTW, I found that even I overdrive my TowerPro servo by 7V5, the torque does not increase that much, so I switched to digital bus servo and found them meeting my requirements. Ref: LX-16A Digital Bus Servo: https://www.amazon.com/LewanSoul-Real-Time-Feedback-Position-Temperature/dp/B0748BQ49M?th=1.

Answer (score -1):

As answered in the Raspberry Pi forum, this is what I'm looking for.
I haven't tried yet, but for someone looking for the same here is the schematic.

[image: circuit]